# Ember: Model's property changes not detected in computed property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models.

models/calendar.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  holidays: hasMany('holiday'),
  date: attr(),
  occasion: attr()
})
```

models/holiday.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  calendar: belongsTo('calendar')
})
```

And a component.

holidays/component.js

```
export default Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.store.find('calendar', this.get('calendarId'))
      .then(calendar => this.set('calendar', calendar));
  },

  calendarIsDirty: computed('calendar.holidays.@each.{date,occasion}', function () {
    // This is not executed
  })
})
```

holidays/template.hbs

```
{{each calendar.holidays as |holiday|}}
  {{input value=holiday.date}}
  {{input value=holiday.occasion}}
{{/each}}

{{#if calendarIsDirty}}
  <button>Save</button>
{{/if}}
```

I'm displaying the holidays in the UI and when the user edits the date or occasion of the holiday, I want to do something. But the computed property that listens to these changes is not executed at all. Kindly help me with this.

I have an 'Add Holiday' button that adds an empty holiday that the user can edit. When I add a holiday, that computed property is executed. Only when I make changes to an existing holiday, the computed property is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is simple that you assume that `this.store.findAll('calendar')` returns a single `calendar`, but it returns a list of `calendar`s.

So with this: `this.set('calendar', calendar)` you set `calendar` to an array of `calendar`s.

Next your dependency key `calendar.holidays.@each` is wrong because `calendar` is an array and so has no property `holidays`.

If you want a single `calendar` you should do a `findId` or `queryRecord`. If you want an array of calendars you should change your code accordingly. However you need to know that `foo.@each.bar.@each` is not a valid dependency key - this is a limitation of ember. you would need to work around this.

Comment: Sorry, I did just this. Mistyped the question. Now updated.

Comment: By the way, I solved it in a hacky way. I added one more property `holidaysAsArray: computed('holidays.@each.hasDirtyAttributes', function () { return this.get('holidays').toArray() })` and used it for listing and changes `calendar.holidays.@each.{date,occasion}` to `calendar.holidaysAsArray.@each.{date,occasion}` in `calendarIsDirty`. It now detects changes as expected.